# RewriteRule doesn't work when it should, why?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want clean urls and my RewriteRule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Z0-9-]+) /articles/index.php?slug=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

which works fine but I also want lower case letters to be handled, and that's the parth which messes it all up and gives me an Internal Server Problem. If I change the above code to this...

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /articles/index.php?slug=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

...then I get Internal Server Problem. The apache error log says:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Anyone knows why I get this error when the only thing I do is to add handling of lower case letters?

Comment: I just wrote what the log said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your pattern: it doesn't have an ending symbol ($).

So when you call /articles/index.php..., it matches, because of /articles/index. Hence the redirect loop.

If you change your pattern like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ...
```

It will work, because the dot character (.) won't match.

Comment: Thanks mate. Works fine now. Can't believe I missed the ending dollar sign :)

Answer (score 0):

### Also

You're using `...&%{QUERY_STRING}`. If there is no query string you end up with `...&` which could look like an empty superfluous parameter to whatever is processing the URL.

`mod_rewrite` has special handling of query strings so you don't need this. If you add the flag `[QSA]` it means that any query string material you added in the rewrite (denoted by a `?`) will be recognized and combined with the existing query string.